# Theano cost function

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, theano

I am trying to learn how to use Theano. I work very frequently with survival analysis and I wanted therefore to try to implement a standard survival model using Theano's automatic differentiation and gradient descent. The model that I am trying to implement is called the Cox model and here is the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model

Very helpfully, they have written there the partial likelihood function, which is what is maximized when estimating the parameters of a Cox model. I am quite new to Theano and as a result am having difficulties implementing this cost function and so I am looking for some guidance.

Here is the code I have written so far. My dataset has 137 records and hence the reason I hard-coded that value. T refers to the tensor module, and W refers to what the wikipedia article calls beta, and status is what wikipedia calls C. The remaining variables are identical to wikipedia's notation.

```
def negative_log_likelihood(self, y, status):
    v = 0
    for i in xrange(137):
        if T.eq(status[i], 1):
            v += T.dot(self.X[i], self.W)
            u = 0
            for j in xrange(137):
                if T.gt(y[j], y[i]):
                    u += T.exp(T.dot(self.X[j], self.W))
            v -= T.log(u)

    return T.sum(-v)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code, I am unhappily met with an infinite recursion error, which I hoped would not happen. This makes me think that I have not implemented this cost function in the way that Theano would like and so I am hoping to get some guidance on how to improve this code so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing symbolic and non-symbolic operations but this doesn't work.

For example, `T.eq` returns a non-executable *symbolic* expression representing the idea of comparing two things for equality but it doesn't actually do the comparison there and then. `T.eq` actually returns a Python object that represents the equality comparison and since a non-`None` object reference is considered the same as `True` in Python, the execution will always continue inside the if statement.

If you need to construct a Theano computation involving conditionals then you need to use one of its two symbolic conditional operations: `T.switch` or `theano.ifelse.ifelse`. [See the documentation for examples and details](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conditions.html).

You are also using Python loops which is probably not what you need. To construct a Theano computation that explicitly loops you need to use the [`theano.scan` module](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html). However, if you can express your computation in terms of matrix operations (dot products, reductions, etc.) then it will run much, much, faster than something using scans.

I suggest you work through some more [Theano tutorials](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/) before trying to implement something complex from scratch.